# How to make content at end of column with 100% height scrollable?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

**Requirements:**

Main row must be 100% height. If rows overflow column than column must be scrollable. Rows must be added in the end of column.

**Now:**

When row height is 100% and rows is overflowed column scroll doesn't work. But if they aren't overflowed it, rows added in the end. But if i remove 100% height that scroll works but rows don't add in the end.

**When height 100%:**

[image: v1]

**When height removed:**

[image]

My code. It doesn't work in code snippet...

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container h-100">
      <div class="row h-100 align-items-end" style="background-color: red;">
        <div class="col-12" style="overflow-y: auto;">
          <div class="row" style="height: 80px; background-color: blue; border: 4px solid black;"></div>
          <div class="row" style="height: 80px; background-color: blue; border: 4px solid black;"></div>
          <div class="row" style="height: 80px; background-color: blue; border: 4px solid black;"></div>
          <div class="row" style="height: 80px; background-color: blue; border: 4px solid black;"></div>
          <div class="row" style="height: 80px; background-color: blue; border: 4px solid black;"></div>
          <div class="row" style="height: 80px; background-color: blue; border: 4px solid black;"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Of, if you are in the need of having **ROWS**, it may be a good idea to use a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use min-height `vh` in the outer `row`.

```
.container>.row {
   min-height:100vh;
}
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/iFOOrsEKZa

---

Edit: To make the bottom aligned div ***scrollable*** per comments, use `mt-auto` instead of align-items-end, and then set a `max-height` on the parent `row`...

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row" style="background-color: red;">
    <div class="col-12 mh-100 mt-auto" style="overflow-y: auto;">
      <div class="row" style="height: 80px; background-color: blue; border: 4px solid black;"></div>
      <div class="row" style="height: 80px; background-color: blue; border: 4px solid black;"></div>
      <div class="row" style="height: 80px; background-color: blue; border: 4px solid black;"></div>
      <div class="row" style="height: 80px; background-color: blue; border: 4px solid black;"></div>
      <div class="row" style="height: 80px; background-color: blue; border: 4px solid black;"></div>
      <div class="row" style="height: 80px; background-color: blue; border: 4px solid black;"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/IPTKiFgNA8

Answer (score 0):

Is there any particular reason you have the red div as a parent property of the blue div instead of as a sibling? try setting the `overflow-y` property of `.container` to scroll like so:

```css
.container {
  overflow-y: scroll;  
 }
```